# Google Chrome Dictionary Location

Tags: google-chrome, dictionary

I'm trying to find the dictionary file for Google Chrome on OS X - I'd like to remove certain words from the dictionary so that I don't use them when writing email (such as 'foolish' for example).

In Firefox, this was a simply a matter of editing the dictionary file, but I'm not sure were I would find it in Chrome?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It doesn't appear that there is a user-editable file with the default dictionary in it. I just looked through the .app folder and saw nothing like a dictionary. Also, `~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Dictionaries/` doesn't list any dictionaries.

#### OS X

The file for the custom dictionary is:

```
/Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Custom Dictionary.txt
```

You may also find it at:

```
/Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Custom Dictionary.txt
```

In the comments, it's mentioned that you can find “misclicks” here, too, which is related to how OS X handles its dictionary:

```
/Users/<user>/Library/Spelling/LocalDictionary
```

#### Windows XP and Windows 7/Vista

[It appears](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=489dc2497b4df3a5&hl=en) it's in (for Windows XP and Vista/7, respectively):

```
C:\Documents and Settings\%USERNAME%\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Custom Dictionary.txt
C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Custom Dictionary.txt
```

#### Linux

The location depends on whether you're running `Chromium` or `Google Chrome`

**Chrome**: `~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Custom Dictionary.txt`

**Chromium**: `~/.config/chromium/Default/Custom Dictionary.txt`

---

If you are using a non-default profile, instead of the directory named `Default`, check for a directory named `Profile n` where `n` is a number starting from 1.

Comment: In my case, it is in ...\Chrome\User Data\`Default`\Custom Dictionary.txt

Comment: I am adding this because I misread the previous statement as a folder name `User Data Default` instead of two folders `User Data\Default` C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Custom Dictionary.txt.  This is in Windows 7 and using Chrome 44.0.2403.125.

Comment: I second @helpYou.  Perhaps it changed for Yosemite or other new versions of OS X?  It's worth a +1 if anyone figures that out.

Comment: Maybe you know where is this dictionary at Linux?

Comment: @VitalyZdanevich Probably `~/.config/google-chrome/Custom Dictionary.txt`. Please confirm if that's where it is.

Comment: @slhck `~/.config/chromium/Profile 2/Custom Dictionary.txt`

Comment: I ran into this problem just now on OSX and found the Chrome dictionary at: `/Users/<user>/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Custom Dictionary.txt`.  Chrome also "helpfully" added my misclick to: `/Users/<user>/Library/Spelling/LocalDictionary`, which I removed. (Hat tip: the [Chrome Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/chrome/YxCxWQXYqJI/awO2TJ0sCAAJ).)

Comment: FYI, in Debian 6 (Squeeze), I found my subject custom dictionary here: `~/.config/chromium/Custom Dictionary.txt`.  IHTH someone!

Comment: I was looking for the complete English dictionary Chrome uses for spell check, not the list of custom words. Also this file contained this, which I never defined: `callables equirectangular ethnicities favorited foederati googled introspectable unintelligibility unsourced` and in fact, when I type them right now, all but `googled` are underlined in red.

Answer (score 19):

For future reference, I found it under:

```
/Users/username/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Custom Dictionary.txt
```

OSX Lion 10.7.4
Chrome 19.0.1084.56
June 2012

Comment: Still in the Chrome/Default/ folder on nearly four years later on Yosemite. :)

Comment: Works on El Capitan too.

Comment: Also you may want to correct it in: `~/Library/Spelling/LocalDictionary` too

Answer (score 13):

### Add a new word to the dictionary

If the spell-checker keeps underlining a word that you often use, right-click the word and select **Add to dictionary**.

*Windows, Chrome OS, and Linux only:* Words that you choose to add to the dictionary are added to your "Custom spelling dictionary".

### Edit your Custom spelling dictionary

1. Click the Chrome menu on the browser toolbar.
2. Select **Settings**.
3. Click **Show advanced settings**.
4. In the "Languages" section, click **Languages and input settings**.
5. Click **Custom spelling dictionary**.
6. In the open text field, type the new word that you want to add. To remove a word that you've previously added, hover over the word and click **X**.
7. Click **Done**.

Source: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95604?hl=en
Checked: October 4, 2014.  Rechecked May 26, 2015.

[image]

Comment: This process has changed in 2023 with Chrome 108+. Instead it's Settings > Languages > Customize Spell Check (at the bottom)

Comment: I'm on Chrome 118 and both options appear to work.

Answer (score 4):

This accepted answer is incorrect or out-of-date w/r/t Google Chrome on Windows. This is where Google Chrome version "31.0.1650.63 m" actually stores the custom dictionary:

\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Custom Dictionary.txt

It's just a text file, with LF-only line terminations, and a list of words in case-sensitive alphabetical order, one per line. There's a checksum at the end, with no LF at the end of that line.

There's also a backup version, in the same folder, named "Custom Dictionary.txt.backup".

According to this
https://chromiumcodereview.appspot.com/11414282
if the checksum fails to match in the regular version of the Custom Dictionary, and there's a backup version with a correct checksum, Chrome will silently discard the regular version and revert to the backup version.

Maybe that's be why Chrome keeps losing my custom dictionary words.  :-(

So I think if you want to edit the custom dictionary file (e.g., to remove misspelled words), you'll need to delete the backup version, to prevent Chrome from reverting to it. (Note: I've not actually done this.)

Comment: I checked and this answer is correct. FYI, when I opened the files (in notepad++) I discovered that each line appears twice - I do not know why. The last line in my case with the checksum, looks like this: 
**checksum_v1 = d9d0767ba5ff29b6c0f1862e88a0d646**

Comment: This answer is now incorrect.

Comment: What is incorrect, slm?

I just checked, and on my computer the dictionary is still:

\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Custom Dictionary.txt

Comment: There's two backup files in my folder, there's a .backup and a .bak.  Perhaps the file name was changed between 2020/9/2 and 2020/11/21?

Comment: Denise, I still have only "Custom Dictionary.txt" and "Custom Dictionary.txt.backup" (dated 10/31/2021 and 10/30/2021, respectively), in my %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\ folder.

Answer (score 4):

The actual dictionary is baked into the browser when it is compiled, so you can't normally find or edit it without re-compiling Chrome yourself. That said, there are a bunch of dictionaries, and they're all listed here:

https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/hunspell_dictionaries/

Comment: I don't understand why this answer received a downvote: my dictionary file is located at `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\chrome\Application\Dictionaries\en-US-8-0.bdic`. The `convert_dict` tool would be required to create a new binary `.bdic` file with words removed. `Custom Dictionary.txt` seems to only support adding words.

Comment: As of May 2020, in Windows the folder is `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data`. The binary dictionary files I found were `en-US-9-0.bdic` and `en-US-8-0.bdic`

Answer (score 2):

Location of Custom Dictionary.txt on MAC has changed yet again. This is due to the fact that Chrome now supports multiple user profiles.

It is now:

```
/Users/username/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Profile 1/
```

Profile 1 will change based on which account is used.

- Browser: Chrome 49
- OS: Mac OS X El Captan 10.11.2

Comment: This worked for me:

`nano /Users/<username>/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Profile\ 1//Custom\ Dictionary.txt`. Delete word(s) you don't want there, press `ctrl+X`, `Y`, `enter`. Should fix it for you.