# Where is Chrome "App dictionaries" path?

Tags: windows, google-chrome

When I run Chrome with the `--diagnostics` flag enabled,
it fails at the "App dictionaries directory path" test and aborts.

I can't find any details about where this path is supposed to be so I can check its permissions and whether it exists or not.

Screenshot of failing tests:

[image]

This test fails on a complete fresh install after reinstalling, and with a blank user profile.

Comment: Take a look: http://superuser.com/questions/280181/google-chrome-dictionary-location

Comment: @duDE I found that, but it appears to be for custom dictionaries, not the built-in ones. Or so I assume. EDIT: That file (Custom Dictionary.txt) is created once I add some words to the custom dictionary from Chrome settings, but the test is still failing, so I don't think that is the file "App dictionaries" is referring to.

Comment: This was reported as a [bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=336763) - status is marked as "Archiving unconfirmed issues, which have not been modified (commented on, updated, etc...) in over 1 year."